# How to make a calculation with a fixed reference that shifts every day in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, dataframe

My data is intraday stock prices data, multiple days. This is a simplified version:

```
                     Last                                                   
2015-01-02 08:30:00  2035.00
2015-01-02 10:30:00  2038.25                    
2015-01-02 15:15:00  2025.25  
2015-01-05 08:30:00  2020.25  
2015-01-05 10:30:00  2010.75                      
2015-01-05 15:15:00  2015.00                  
2015-01-06 08:30:00  1988.00 
2015-01-06 10:30:00  1990.25                     
2015-01-06 15:15:00  1970.00
```

Given that in the data, every day, the last row is at 15:15:00, how can I take the difference (15:15:00 Row - Last), for every row per day. Here's the desired output.

```
                     Last      Dif                                             
2015-01-02 08:30:00  2035.25  -10 
2015-01-02 10:30:00  2038.25  -13                  
2015-01-02 15:15:00  2025.25   0
2015-01-05 08:30:00  2020.25  -5.25
2015-01-05 10:30:00  2010.00   5                   
2015-01-05 15:15:00  2015.00   0               
2015-01-06 08:30:00  1988.00  -18
2015-01-06 10:30:00  1990.25  -20.25                    
2015-01-06 15:15:00  1970.00   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by [`DatetimeIndex.day`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.day.html) and [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) difference between last value by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html) and actual row value:

```
print df
                        Last
2015-01-02 08:30:00  2035.25
2015-01-02 10:30:00  2038.25
2015-01-02 15:15:00  2025.25
2015-01-05 08:30:00  2020.25
2015-01-05 10:30:00  2010.00
2015-01-05 15:15:00  2015.00
2015-01-06 08:30:00  1988.00
2015-01-06 10:30:00  1990.25
2015-01-06 15:15:00  1970.00

df['Dif'] = df.groupby(df.index.day)['Last'].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-1] - x)
print df
                        Last    Dif
2015-01-02 08:30:00  2035.25 -10.00
2015-01-02 10:30:00  2038.25 -13.00
2015-01-02 15:15:00  2025.25   0.00
2015-01-05 08:30:00  2020.25  -5.25
2015-01-05 10:30:00  2010.00   5.00
2015-01-05 15:15:00  2015.00   0.00
2015-01-06 08:30:00  1988.00 -18.00
2015-01-06 10:30:00  1990.25 -20.25
2015-01-06 15:15:00  1970.00   0.00
```